# How to add a counter to this loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm a javascript newbie working on a hangman game, I had everything working properly until I realized that my method for comparing my guess to the answer was unable to handle words with multiple letters. I've written a new loop that takes care of this, but that's led to a new problem: I don't know how to work in a counter to keep track of wrong guesses.

This is the loop that I have:

```
function checkGuess(guess, array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let found = false;
        for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] === guess) {
                found = true;
            } 
        }
        if (found) {
            results += answer[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The game will end when the number of wrong guesses reaches a certain count or when results.length = answer.length but I can't figure out how to handle wrong guesses. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: these two loops iterating over same set of array?

Comment: Maybe there are some typos in the code?

Comment: Yes, the two loops iterate over the same array. Anything I've tried for the counter has either incremented whether it's right or wrong or incremented once for every letter in the word that is not the guess(i.e if the word is "foo" and I guess "f" the counter goes up two)

Comment: As @brk said, the two loops are basically doing the same thing. Maybe, for the first loop, instead of using `array.length`, you can give the number of wrong guesses you allow the user to have. And then you can use a `if .. else statement` outside the for loop to check if the user's guess was correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe what you're looking for?

```
var wrongGuesses = 0;
function checkGuess(guess, array) {

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let found = false;
        let go_time = false;
        for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] === guess) {
                found = true;
                results += answer[i];
            }
            if(j===(array.length-1)){
                go_time = true;
            }
        }
        if (go_time===true&&found!==true) {
            wrongGuesses++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, create a function that return the number of places that the guess exists

```
function checkGuess(guess, array) {
    let found = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === guess) {
            found++;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

then use 2 vars to hold the correct guess and the wrong guess

```
var correct = 0, wrong = 0
```

then every time the user is guessing, do the following:

```
var check = checkGuess(guess, question);
if (check > 0) {
    correct += check;
} else {
    wrong++;
}
```

to determine if win or lose

```
if (wrong >= 3) {
    // set it to lose
}
if (correct == question.length) {
    // set it to win
}
```

Comment: This ended up being exactly what I needed. I was probably overthinking the problem a bit/making it unnecessarily complicated but this has got me back on the right track. Thank you very much!

Comment: actually it still has a problem in it, it does not track which guess has been guessed correctly, so if the secret word is "secret" you can win it by guessing "s" 6 times, to keep track of things I have created a little example for you https://jsfiddle.net/j215nqpk/